# Attempting to typecheck a function in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am not sure how to describe my problem, but essentially I am attempting to type-check a function but I am unsure if my understanding is correct.

I have these props over here

```
  const { closeModal, productId, activeEnvironment } = props;
```

Now I already know that productId is a string and so is activeEnvironment, but closeModal is a function, now I figured this out by outputting it to the console in a console log statement.

This is what was outputted in the browser console.

```
 ƒ closeModal() {
  setManualBeatModalOpen(false);
}
```

Here is the usage of my ManualPulseModal

```
<ManualBeatForm
        productId={productId}
        closeModal={() => {
          setManualBeatModalOpen(false);
        }}
        activeEnvironment={activeEnvironment}
      />
```

Now how would I type check the closeModal variable do I need to use Dispatch....etc

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'type check' in this scenario? Can you describe what specific *behaviour* you are looking for?

Comment: For example I understand if I was to typecheck. a string variable I would do

myVar:string

But what happens if it is a function, this is the question I am asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `closeModal` has no parameters and no return value, you can type it simply as `closeModal : () => void`.

So you could have something similar to this (excluding the other props):

```
interface Props {
  closeModal : () => void
}

export function YourFunc(props : Props) {
  const { closeModal } = props;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Unsure why this got rated down - it has the answer.